# Can I store an .exe file in my Android app and run it on pc after connecting via bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, exe

I am building an Android app in which I need to run a program (.exe file) that is stored in my app. After I connect the phone to a pc via bluetooth, I want to send the program that is stored (in a .exe format for example) in the app to the pc and run it on the pc. The idea is basically that I will be able to run the program on every computer I connect to my phone. Is that possible? If so, how do I do something like that?

Comment: Smells like a **malware**. Or should I say "stinks"?

Comment: Yeah, this screams malware. Any self respecting security software is going to block this.

Comment: But is there a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

`exe` is Microsoft Windows compatible executable. So with an `exe` you won't cover OS X and Linux systems. Even with Microsoft you would need to build executable for 32 and 64 bit systems, detect and decide which one to deploy. With Linux you'd also need to build and deploy 32 or 64 bit `ELF` executables and `.so` (shared libraries).

Not to mention some tablets which are ARM architecture based.

What's your use case? You probably better off building a server for the user base and offer solutions there, probably distributing your companion tool and detecting OSes there for download. What you are trying to do is so similar to malware, so otherwise you'd run into so many roadblocks, you'd fight endlessly with anti-virus and anti-malware tools and measures.

Comment: not a malware at all... It is a school project and I had this idea. It doesn't have to fit all systems - just Windows is OK. Just want to check if it is possible.

Comment: I don't say it is a malware, but the use-case is similar to a malware. If you can pull this off that would be an amazing feat.

Comment: Do you know how  I can build such a thing?

Comment: @roeihapoel8810 You need to know about the platforms you target. Then also implement the deployment. Given how many platforms you target this can be really difficult. If you target just a few platforms make sure you exclude the others and fail gracefully on them.